# Error while sending a mail in php

Tags: php

I am using  the mail function of php to send the mail so for i am calling the function like

```
mail($EMAIL_HOST_USER, "Invitation for conference ", $message);
```

but i am getting an unexpected error

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'mail' (T_STRING) in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/UI/user/usernotify.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />
```

i am not sure where i am doing wrong .

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is basic syntax error, probably missing ';'

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error on some line above the line you show - most likely you forgot a semi-colon or something like that.

Comment: thanks actually i am from python background so i am missing it

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer has solved your problem, do you mind accepting it?